# LinearLayout not scrolling when keyboard is appearing

Tags: android, android-layout

I am facing a problem with ScrollView. When the keyboard is appearing, scrollview is not scrolling till the end of the view.

Here is my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Add Member"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="@dimen/heading_text_size"
        android:background="@color/heading"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/search_member_number"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:hint="Enter mobile number"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/searchExistingUserButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Search"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:background="#FF9800"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:hint="Enter member name"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="Address"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtContact"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="Mobile No"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtReferredBy"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="Referred by"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtKittyGroups"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="Enter kitty group name"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/admin_setup_buttons_text_size"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtRepeat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="Enter repeat number"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/createUserButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="Create Member"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:background="#BBDEFB"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have seen several posts in stackoverflow, but unfortunately none is working. What could be the possible solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is causing by adjustPan . Where adjust Pan does not resize the window, it pans the view so that whatever has focus is never obscured by the soft keyboard.

Add this to your AndroidManifest.xml . This might do the trick.

Example:

```
<activity android:name="YourActivity" 
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Comment: Tried this. Unfortunately this is not solving the issue.

Comment: What actually happens when you try to scroll to the bottom when the keyboard is on ?? dose it get stuck on a specific height ? have you tried the offset the layout from the bottom and see if it works ??

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your layout:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `<Space/>` and

```
 android:layout_height="100dp"
```

give height static which you want.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Add Member"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="@dimen/heading_text_size"
            android:background="@color/heading"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/search_member_number"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:hint="Enter mobile number"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:inputType="phone"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/searchExistingUserButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Search"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:background="#FF9800"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:hint="Enter member name"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:hint="Address"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtContact"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:hint="Mobile No"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtReferredBy"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:hint="Referred by"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtKittyGroups"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:hint="Enter kitty group name"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="8"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/admin_setup_buttons_text_size"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtRepeat"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:hint="Enter repeat number"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/createUserButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="Create Member"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:background="#BBDEFB"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <Space
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```